# Regular expression wildcard and searching arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to loop through an array and compare the strings within it, to another string and add those to a new array.

```js
var adUnitMacro = 'news'
var verticalOutput = []

keywordArray = ['news', 'homepage', 'technology', 'entertainment', 'sport',
  'business', 'lifestyle', 'travel', 'motoring', 'property'
]

for (i = 0; i < keywordArray.length; i++) {
  if (keywordArray[i] === adUnitMacro) {
    verticalOutput.push(keywordArray[i]);
  }
}

console.log(verticalOutput)
console.log(keywordArray[0])
```

In this example 'news' gets added to the verticalOutput array.  But if the adUnitMacro variable is '123news123' nothing gets added to the verticalOutput array as the 'news' in the keyword array isn't an exact match.

How can I make is so if the string of characters in the keyword array is present in the adUnitMacro those values will be pushed into the verticalOutput array?

For example if `adUnitMacro = 'newshomepagetechnology'`

The `verticalOutput` array would be `['news', 'homepage', 'technology']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `keywordArray[i] === adUnitMacro` to `adUnitMacro.includes(keywordArray[i])`.

Your code would end up looking like this:

```
var adUnitMacro = 'news'
var verticalOutput = []

keywordArray = ['news', 'homepage', 'technology', 'entertainment', 'sport',
  'business', 'lifestyle', 'travel', 'motoring', 'property'
]

for (i = 0; i < keywordArray.length; i++) {
  if (adUnitMacro.includes(keywordArray[i])) {
    verticalOutput.push(keywordArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var adUnitMacro = 'newshomepagetechnology'
var verticalOutput = []

keywordArray = ['news', 'homepage', 'technology', 'entertainment', 'sport',
  'business', 'lifestyle', 'travel', 'motoring', 'property'
]

for (i = 0; i < keywordArray.length; i++) {
  if (adUnitMacro.includes(keywordArray[i])) {
    verticalOutput.push(keywordArray[i]);
  }
}

console.log(verticalOutput)
console.log(keywordArray[0])
```